# Nothing happens when clicking submit

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using WordPress with Custom Content Types plugin. I have the code in a PHP file which creates a contact form.

The website is http://schools.raci.org.au/competition/ancq/

It was working fine before I migrated it to a new host. I didn't write the original code, so I don't really know how it works.

Here are the relevant files:

Here is the code for the main page: pastebin.com/piaTSVgc

and the code for the form: pastebin.com/xeqsmc5g

here is admin-ajax.php: pastebin.com/eFx2JFJu

here is the function where register_interest_form lives: pastebin.com/knrChkSP

here is functions.php: pastebin.com/hru5LkQR

Thanks in advance!

Comment: u havent specified any action

Comment: its working, u can see ajax triggered after submitting, on network tab

Comment: yeah I can see that, but nothing *happens*.  that's what I can't figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Its working from.

**When we submit form. there is ajax request is been processing and getting 0 in response.**

The default response from admin-ajax.php is,

```
die( '0' );
```

...by adding your own `exit()` or `die()` after returning your desired content prevents the default response from `admin-ajax.php` being returned as well.

*The solution is to add die() to the end of your own ajax function, so you die the script before die('0')*

It also generally means that your ajax call has succeeded.

Ultimately, to answer your question, it's meant to work this way. What you are doing by exiting after returning your content is the right thing to do.

details from.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/116759/why-does-wordpress-add-0-zero-to-an-ajax-response

Comment: Hi Jitendra - thanks for the insight.  However I'm not really a PHP guy (I inherited this code).  Can you tell me how to fix it in detail?  Thanks a bunch!